# alignment in android activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set height of both the textview and edit text both to wrap content and are algined side by side to each other but still for a single line of same text they don't seem to be aligned side by side ...why is this happening....i want to align them side by side.

[image]

My current code is->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/serverLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/serverIp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Server IP"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/serverIpDetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="server ip" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/serverLayout"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:text="CLick me" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the two are not the same height.  An edit view is taller, because it has the bar to show its an edit field.  If you want them to align, put `layout_alignBaseline="@+id/serverIp"` on the text layout.  AlignBaseline will align the bottom of the text on each.

Comment: This should be the answer with a small correction put `layout_alignBaseline="@+id/serverIp"` on the EditText layout or   `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/serverIpDetail"` with TextView

Answer (score 1):

Use ConstraintLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/serverIp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Server IP"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/serverIpDetail"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/serverIpDetail" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/serverIpDetail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:hint="server ip"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="CLick me"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/serverIpDetail" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Or if you want something like this, try the code below:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/serverIp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="Server IP"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/serverIpDetail"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/serverIpDetail"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/serverIpDetail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="server ip"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/serverIp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="CLick me"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/serverIpDetail" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way--

use linear layout instead of relative layout.Then inside a vertical linear layout use two horizontal linear layout.This two liner layout (horizontal) will contain your textview and edittext respectively.

something like this--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    android:orientation="vertical"
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/serverLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="30dp">

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/serverLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="30dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/serverIp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Server IP"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/serverLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="30dp">

            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/serverIpDetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="server ip" />


            </LinearLayout>





    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/serverLayout"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:text="CLick me" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/serverLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/serverIpDetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="server ip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/serverIp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Server IP"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/serverLayout"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:text="CLick me" />


</RelativeLayout>
```